# How can avoid symlink problems with npm running in Docker on a Windows host?

Tags: node.js, windows, docker, npm, symlink

I am using the [latest Docker public beta](https://www.docker.com/products/docker#/windows) on Windows 10.

I am developing a Node.js app and I am using Docker with my src directory mounted as a volume in a container.

I cannot run `npm install` from inside the container because it will cause the creation of symbolic links (in the node_modules directory), that apparently are not supported in volumes if the host is Windows.

Is there anything I can do to solve this problem?

I have no issues on running this in a Linux environment.

After some research I found many solutions involving Virtualbox, being for the "old" version of Docker (Docker Toolbox).

Comment: What's the project you're trying to build? Alternatively, can you provide a simple example that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved in the following way.

I'll use `/usr/src` as the directory to mount to in the container in this example:

1. Mount the src directory of your app on `/usr/src`: `-v /path/to/src:/usr/src`
2. Define a data volume for `node_modules`: `-v /usr/src/node_modules`

In this way you will have that `/path/to/src` will be mounted to `/usr/src` and `/usr/src/node_modules` will be mounted as a data volume.

The final result is that the even though a `node_modules` directory is created on the host, it will stay empty.

This solution exploits [Docker Data Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/v1.11/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/).

This is applicable every time you want to avoid that changes in a subdirectory of a mounted directory to be reflected on the host, not just for `node_modules`.

Comment: This worked for me. Not the greatest, but it works. We just use docker-compose for local development environments anyway.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid `symlink` error with NPM you can use command:

```
npm install --no-bin-links
```

However, to absolutely avoid `symlink` issue, you should not set your nodejs project in the mounted directory (mounted from Window)

Comment: I tried with that already, but it seems I cannot run my gulp tasks :( Those packages should be installed as global ones, right?

Comment: With Front-end code, you should not build it in Docker Container. I think you build in host and mount it into Docker by `COPY`. But If you are trying to use Docker for Development Environment. I think that it is not good way.

Comment: The second suggestion is the real one! Dude, you saved my life! What a brilliant idea. To elaborate a bit more. I was battling an issue between Docker + Windows + Magento + Grunt and I wasn't able to compile the themes as grunt was trying to create symlinks in the pub folder and somehow they turned corrupted. When I used your suggestion i.e. create a master symlink to a local (for Docker's vm) folder - it worked like a charm!